# UITableView displaying 'phantom cell'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In certain cases in my tablecells, an image is added to the cell.  My cells are not properly displaying.  Here is a picture of what I mean:

[image]

The second lock icon doesn't belong there...im not sure how or why its ending up there.  In this example, the array has a count of 2 so the additional lock is not even inside of a cell.

This never happens on the initial load but happens as soon as the cells are reloaded the first time.  This is also confusing to me because the initial load function is the same as the reload function.

Here's the code for the cell itself:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [UITableViewCell configureFlatCellWithColor:[UIColor greenSeaColor] selectedColor:[UIColor wetAsphaltColor] reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier inTableView:(UITableView *)tableView];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        [cell configureFlatCellWithColor:[UIColor greenSeaColor] selectedColor:[UIColor wetAsphaltColor]];

    }

    Room *room;

    //is data filtered?
    if(isFiltered)
    room = [filteredTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    else
    room = [roomList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    cell.textLabel.text = room.roomName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = room.hostUsername;

    //lock icon or not
  if(room.password != nil)
{
    UIImageView *pw = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    pw.tag = [room.rid integerValue];
    [pw setImage:img];
    pw.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width - cell.frame.size.height, cell.frame.origin.y,
                          cell.frame.size.height - 2, cell.frame.size.height - 2);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:pw];
}
else{ //remove the content view if not needed
    [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:[room.rid integerValue]] removeFromSuperview];
}


    return cell;
}
```

For the record, this does not happen iOS7 (I know it's under NDA but just wanted to mention that fact if it helps).

Comment: that is not a phantom cell. :) it is simple autoresize-mask issue only; the cell will appear later, and the frame size is undefined when `–tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` invoked and you put the lock icon at a totally wrong position. 1) set _absolute_ coordinates for the `pw`'s frame instead of _relative_ ones, **OR** 2) set the autoresize-mask properly for the `pw` object.

Answer (score 2):

The icon is not cleared on the reused cells, so remove the pw view if it doesn't have a password

```
if(room.password != nil)
{
    ...
    pw.tag = 12345;
} else {
    [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:12345] removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Of course, I would recommend you assign this view to the cell's `accessoryView` instead of doing it like you are now, but this answers your question. See the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info on `accessoryView`

Comment: thanks, i thought the problem was along these lines but its still showing up.

Comment: I bet you are adding a new view every time, on top of existing lock views.

Comment: Yes you're right it looks that way, eventually this will be subclassed and done properly but what I don't understand is why there's a third `cell`?  Shouldn't they be layering on top of each other?  If I can even call it a cell as there's no interactivity on it.  I watch it run with a debugger and the array count never goes past 2 elements.  I've also updated the code above with your additions.

Comment: subclassing fixed it...still dont understand why it was happening but thanks

Comment: You are trying to lookup the tag based on the current rid, not the old one. use a fixed value (such as 12345 like I said) , not a dynamic one.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating my own UITableViewCell, initializing the image and used these two functions for the lock:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"password.png"];                 
        pw = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
        [pw setImage:img];
        pw.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width - self.frame.size.height, self.frame.origin.y,
                              self.frame.size.height - 2, self.frame.size.height - 2);
        pw.tag = 1;

    }
    return self;
}
-(void)enableLock{
    [self.contentView addSubview:pw];
}

-(void)disableLock{
    [[self.contentView viewWithTag:1]removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: While subclassing your table view cells is recommended it has nothing to do with the fix. It is only working now because you have the viewWithTag call setup correctly.